# MySQL выдает 2013 ошибку

Tags: mysql

Вся база из 400000 записей, но раньше не было таких проблем и с запросами побольше. Ноут начинает шуметь после запроса:

```sql
SELECT
   client_id,
   count(distinct db_Sales.id) as sales,
   count(distinct db_EmailActivity.message_id) as messages 
FROM
   product.db_Actions 
   LEFT join
      product.db_Contacts 
      on db_Actions.user_id = db_Contacts.user_id 
   LEFT join
      product.db_Sales 
      on db_Contacts.id = db_Sales.contact_id 
   LEFT join
      product.db_EmailActivity 
      on db_Contacts.id = db_EmailActivity.contact_id 
group by
   db_Actions. client_id ;
```

Comment: Читайте в логах mysql-сервера, что с ним случилось в момент возникновения ошибки

Comment: Ужс... Посчитайте COUNT в подзапросах, а потом связывайте с остальными таблицами. Зачем сервер-то насиловать?

Comment: Не помогло(((((